90s movie about detective stalked by crazy ex gf
I have some memories about a movie that's really bugging me and I can't find it via Google searches. I saw this and other movies when I was little/teen, in the late 90s and early 2000s. Here's what I remember:

There's this detective who has a female partner called Diane or Diana. 
He is suddenly being stalked by a psychotic blonde ex. She follows him one day with her car, behind his. Then, at a stoplight, she comes out of the car behind him and flashes him (aka shows him her boobs) by unraveling her coat, and he sees her in the rear-view mirror. He later tells this to his partner and they have a laugh together.
At one point, the ex gf sneaks into his shower and tells him "don't worry, I promise to be good" or something like that and they have some sexy time.
The ending is happy in that his partner shoots the crazy ex who I think was trying to kill him.

The 2 detectives kinda look like the main characters in the tv series Silk Stalkings or Hunter. But neither one female protagonist in these is called Diana / Diane. He was in his 40s I think with short hair but no baldness like in Hunter. His partner looked like Mitzi Kapture from Silk Stalkings but thinner.
I think this might also be a TV movie and that's why I'm having a hard time finding out its name. I've had success with other ones from back then but not this one.
Thanks for any help! 
